# get_terms: determine if taxonomy term has children

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, terms

I'm looking to determine if a taxonomy term has children. See the below markup and I'll explain what I mean:

```
<?php
$terms = get_terms("wpsc_product_category");
if ( !empty( $terms ) && !is_wp_error( $terms ) ){
    foreach( get_terms( 'wpsc_product_category', array( 'hide_empty' => false, 'parent' => 0 ) ) as $parent_term ) { ?>
    <li class="header-menu-item" data-hook="<?php echo $parent_term->slug; ?>">
        <a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>/products/<?php echo $parent_term->slug; ?>"><?php echo $parent_term->name; ?></a>                
    </li>
    <?php }
} ?>
```

So this outputs a list of all parent taxonomy terms for the `wpsc_product_category` taxonomy, but I want to determine if the taxonomy term has children or not, and if so add the `parent` class to the relevant `header-menu-item` so I can attach a jquery function to it. I'm not sure if this is possible? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`get_term_children` function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_children) should help here.

This returns an array, either with the child terms inside it, or empty. Checking if this array is truthy or not as you loop through will then let you determine whether or not to add the class.

```
<?php
    $terms = get_terms('wpsc_product_category');
    if ( !empty( $terms ) && !is_wp_error( $terms ) ){
    foreach( get_terms( 'wpsc_product_category', array( 'hide_empty' => false, 'parent' => 0 ) ) as $parent_term ) {
        $term_children = get_term_children($parent_term->term_id, 'wpsc_product_category'); ?>
        <li class="header-menu-item<?php echo ($term_children ? ' parent' : ''); ?>" data-hook="<?php echo $parent_term->slug; ?>">
            <a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>/products/<?php echo $parent_term->slug; ?>"><?php echo $parent_term->name; ?></a>                
        </li>
    <?php }
} ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, doesn't seem to work though? I've implemented the code, to no effect as the `parent` class isn't being added?

Comment: @PieterGoosen voila! That edit has fixed it, worked a charm :)

Answer (score 1):

You might try leveraging [get_term_children](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_children) to generate an array of all the children of that taxonomy, and then check against empty().

Since it returns an empty array, you should be able to do something like this:

(You'll need to find out your term's id, which is a number, and replace it in the below $term_id variable)

```
$term_id = 2
$taxonomy_name = 'wpsc_product_category';
$terms = get_term_children( $term_id, $taxonomy_name );

if ( !empty( $terms ) && !is_wp_error( $terms ) ){
 // do your stuff
}
```